# Changing line thickness in ordihull vegan r package

Tags: r, plot, line, vegan

How can I change the thickness of the boundary lines used in ordihull?

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
mod <- cca(dune ~ Management, dune.env)
attach(dune.env)
plot(mod, type="n", scaling = 3)
pl <- ordihull(mod, Management, scaling = 3, label = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **lwd** argument, see `?par` for details.

```
pl <- ordihull(mod, Management, scaling = 3, label = TRUE, lwd=10)
```

[image: ordihull]